# Is there any simpler way to make this password generator program?

Tags: python-2.x

```
# Password Generator Program

import random

print'''############################################################################
   #                     PASSWORD GENEREATOR SYSTEM                            #                           
   #############################################################################'''



print"Hey, I can generate strong passwords for you \nJust give me two inputs:"
a=input("Enter the length of password you want:\n")
b=input("How many passwords you want?\n")

li=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','W','X','Y','Z',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,'@','#','$','%','&',]

for i in range(1,a+1):
    print "\n"
    for j in range(1,b+1):
        print random.choice(li),
```

I have defined a list and put all the uppercase, lowercase, 0 to 9, special characters in them. But this was very time consuming, so is there any other way to implement the same?

Comment: Look in the string module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html. Also note that 2.x is nearing the end of its life, if you're learning Python I'd recommend 3.x.

Comment: @johnsharpe thanks for this advice but before startred learning python I researched on internet where majority of articles says '"Python 2.x will be more suitable for beginners" then I also think I should learn python2. Can I learn python3 after python2? Will it be easiier or I should start from Python3 because I just learned the basics of python2.

Comment: Any chance you learned that from Zed Shaw/Learn Python the Hard Way? Because https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints, https://eev.ee/blog/2016/11/23/a-rebuttal-for-python-3/. You can learn Python 3 after 2, but it's easier to go straight to the former.

Comment: You are right i started from Python the hard way. Anyway, thanks for guidance. I can still learn Python3.

Comment: [Should I learn Python 2 or 3?](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-2-or-3/) / [Should I use Python 2 or Python 3 for my development activity?](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) / [Python 2 or 3?](https://www.fullstackpython.com/python-2-or-3.html) / [Python 2 vs Python 3: Which to Learn?](https://wsvincent.com/python2-vs-python3/) / [Ask HN: It's 2017, should I learn Python 3 or 2?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13516508) / [Python FAQ: Why should I use Python 3?](https://eev.ee/blog/2016/07/31/python-faq-why-should-i-use-python-3/)

Comment: TL;DR: Zed Shaw hates Python, and he hates you too. Learn Python 3, and burn your copy of LPTHW.